# Is it safe to plug a power strip into a SurgeMaster outlet?

Tags: electrical

Similar to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/169523/is-it-safe-to-daisy-chain-power-bars-power-strips), but not exactly the same, since this is an actual outlet and not a power strip.

[image: SurgeMaster]

Also, is the grounded light supposed to be on? Should I just replace this with a normal outlet?

Comment: There's probably a regular outlet there already, if you remove the screw and pull the 6-port out of the duplex outlet it's almost certainly plugged in to.

Comment: TBH, no, this _isn't_ any different than the linked question. This is a "power strip" that simply plugs into both outlets of a duplex receptacle replacing the cover plate, then gets screwed into place. The ground light is off because the outlet behind this isn't grounded, or something has failed within the unit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to daisy-chain power bars (power strips)?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/169523/is-it-safe-to-daisy-chain-power-bars-power-strips)

Comment: You're right, sorry, there is an outlet back there. It has the plate off so I didn't recognize it at first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you discovered, this is just another cheapazoid power strip, but in a different "form factor".  The real receptacle is behind it.

I'm being a little harsh on Belkin; they are certainly best-in-class among the cheapazoids.  I would consider them a Tier 2 supplier alongside Lutron and Leviton.  I use it myself.  **However, even a top tier power strip (like Tripp-Lite) *is still a power strip* and is not anywhere near as safe as built-in wiring**.

### But it's even worse than that

There are two aspects we really care about: Human protection and machine protection.

For machine protection, this setup as illustrated does not have a safety ground, and while safety ground contributes to protecting humans, it *really* protects machines. **You don't have safety ground**.

For human protection, what we need the most is GFCI protection.  **You can't use a GFCI receptacle at this location, because the bolt-up "power strip" blocks it**.  The outlet *certainly could* be protected by a GFCI device at another location (receptacle upstream, deadfront upstream, or GFCI breaker). In that case the outlet would be fed off the GFCI device's "Load"  terminals. (that's the only thing "Load" should be used for).  You can test that by hitting "Test" on every other GFCI in the house (you're supposed to do that monthly *anyway*) and see if doing so knocks out power here.

### Other than that, Mrs. Lincoln, it can be OK.

**Honestly, what really makes power strips dangerous is uber-cheapies, or asking too much of the power strip**.  [As I said in the other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/169544/47125), chaining power strips is fine if you don't load them very hard.  This is all about "know your amps", which most people have no clue about, so, skill up a bit :)

It goes without saying that a cheap Chinese power strip won't handle as many amps as a quality unit, and one which lacks a competent UL* listing won't handle any amps safely at all. Look at any of Big Clive's teardowns on Youtube to see how that is.

---

---

* Other agencies on the [trusted list of NRTL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_Recognized_Testing_Laboratory) would also suffice, but never CE unless it's bought at a reputable bricks-and-mortar store inside the EU.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not safe to link multiple outlet extenders or power strips. If you remove the screw in the surge master you will find that is plugged into a duplex receptacle.
When looking on line I could not see any overcurrent protection in the device itself only surge protection. So it would not be wise to link this device to another power strip.

Note that device may not be providing full protection without the ground.